# How to add a NOT NULL foreign key to SQlite3 table in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

I am having some trouble adding a foreign key column to an already existing table on SQLite.

Here's my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS director (
    director_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie (
    movie_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE movie ADD COLUMN director_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES
director(director_id);
```

This give me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL
```

However, if I remove the "NOT NULL" constraint it runs fine:

```
ALTER TABLE movie ADD COLUMN director_id INTEGER REFERENCES
director(director_id);
```

The following also works just fine but I already have an existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS director (
    director_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie (
    movie_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    director_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(director_id) REFERENCES director(director_id)
);
```

Am I missing something or it cannot be made in SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

When altering a table to add a column with `NOT NULL`, you need to add a `DEFAULT` value.  Otherwise, it has no idea what to put in an existing record when adding the column (since NULL is not valid).

Docs ref: https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie (
    movie_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE movie ADD COLUMN director_id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 REFERENCES director(director_id);
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want a default. I want a constraint that imply that value cannot be null. If I try to insert a NULL value it should return an error. Your code replaces it with DEFAULT 0. The last example does not have a default.

Comment: I am aware of what you have.  I am telling you what is possible according to the SQLite docs as I linked in the reference.  It is not possible to `ALTER` a table to `ADD COLUMN` with `NOT NULL` without providing a default value.  It specifically states that in the sqlite docs.  It is specified in the statement `If a NOT NULL constraint is specified, then the column must have a default value other than NULL.` under `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN`.

Comment: That said, there are other approaches you can take like copying the table as described in the `Making Other Kinds Of Table Schema Changes` section in the docs.  You can use that procedure to do pretty much whatever you want to the table.